# Choosing some statistical tests

Tags: modeling, model-selection

Imagine one big river (let's call it the river A) and a smaller one (river B). The river B is the tributary of the river A.

I have some data collected including concentration of some important chemical elements and other important things (Mg, Ca, Cl, pH, hardness). I have been collecting them in the river B and in the river A before and after the merge with river B.

My task is to find out if the river B has an impact on the river A and if yes then I am to check how big it is.

Have you ever came across such problem? What statistical tests or methods can I use to draw some conclusions?

Comment: Can you tell us some details? How many sampling points? How many observations at each point? Some other variables? Maybe you can share (a link to) the data, or at least show us some plots for comparison of distributions?